# PDO connection string errors

Tags: php, pdo

this is a login system for a project i am doing so i know it is not secure and will be adding security details at a later date.

i would like to get this part working first but the problem i am having is that when i submit the form it is always taking me to the page that the user gets redirected to if their credentials are wrong.

i have done research and come to this conclusion of code i will not be storing the password as plain text this system is just to start me into using PDO.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    //connection String
    $connection = new PDO("mysql:host=hostname;Database=databasename", "username", "0password"); 
    //Selecting function
    $smt = $connection->prepare("select user_id, email, password from account where email =         :email and password =:password");

    //setting values to textboxes
    $username = $_POST["txt_email"];
    $password = $_POST["txt_password"];

    //binding values
    $smt->bindParam(':email', $email);
    $smt->bindParam(':password', $password);

    //execution
    $smt->execute();

    //fetching data
    $row = $smt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) ;  
    echo "$row[email]\n\n";
    echo "$row[password]\n\n";
    $_SESSION{"user_id"} = $row["user_id"];

    //If Statement
        if ($smt->rowCount() == 0){
            header( "location: log.html");


        } else{

            header("location: home.html");
        }
?>
```

Comment: `$username = $_POST["txt_email"];` shoud be `$email = $_POST["txt_email"];`

Comment: OH haha thanks im an idiot i though i thoroughly read through it haha.

Comment: Also `$_SESSION{"user_id"}`works, but in php `$_SESSION["user_id"]` is more often used. ( also only use double quotes if you need them, using single quotes is quicker )

Comment: oh is that something that is different in PDO from normal PHP?

Comment: Well no, it works, but in PHP brackets are more commonly used instead of curly braces. So to keep your code maintainable ( by other coders aswell that don't know the {} can access arrays too ? ), you should try to use brackets. **Edit:** Also, curly braces can be used as "variable variables" see http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php, so you will mainly just avoid confusion ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$username = $_POST["txt_email"];
$smt->bindParam(':email', $email);
```

I guess `$username` in the first statement should be `$email`

Comment: Thanks for the help i new to programming so bug checking is slightly difficult

Comment: You're welcome :) Remember to look out for such typos when writing code, since they are the most difficult to spot and waste a lot of time.

Comment: so the page still redirects to the log.html as it seems it is wrong data im using a online sql database could that be something to do with it?

Comment: Try to do `var_dump($row['email']);var_dump($row['password']);die()` and see if the values match the ones. In the meantime, make sure you have the specific record in the database. If the values are empty, then something with your query is wrong. Use `$smt->debugDumpParams();` right after `$smt->execute()` to see what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm wrong but `"mysql:host=hostname;Database=databasename"` shouldn't be `"mysql:host=hostname;dbname=databasename"`? so `dbname` instead of `Database`...

Comment: so the page still redirects to the log.html as it seems it is wrong data im using a online sql database could that be something to do with it?

Comment: Do you have errors enabled? Anyway, you can proceed step by step in order to learn the PDO flow here. So what do you get if `var_dump($connection)`?